# Opening Web Page in IE6 Triggers an OnClick Event

Tags: asp.net, events

I have written a web page that provides a drop down list of reports that can be viewed.  The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrdUY/1/.  The image in the fiddle is exactly what you see when you open the page in Firefox (13.0.1) but when the page is opened in IE6 it seems that the "View Report" event is triggered with the visible selection in the drop down list thus immediately rendering that report.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: You have to support IE6? I'm so, so sorry. I can't even test it, either, because I don't want a paid Browserling, e.g. account and the Microsoft-provided IE6 testing image expired a while ago. (And I imagine that's probably the case for most people here.)

Comment: Why would anyone ever want to open a webpage with IE6? Unless he has been in coma for the past 5/6 years, I can't find any other reasonable explanation. Was this the case for your system administrator? How do you even expect us testing this? You expect someone having IE6 still installed?

Comment: Not sure why we are using such an old browser.  I'm just trying to work with what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird.  The problem simply went away.